# How do I link to a PDF file in Silex?

Tags: silex

I've looked around a bit and can't seem to figure out how to link to a static file while using Silex. I've seen some similar questions/answers in regards to Symfony, but they involved YML routing files, which I don't use with Silex.

**My Situation**

I have some files in a /docs folder. Logged in users can upload new pdf files (so, I don't know ahead of time what all of the filenames will be; they're constantly changing).

**My Intent**

I need to be able to link to these PDF files, so that a click on a link somewhere will open www.myurl.com/docs/myfile.pdf.

**The Problem**

Due to the routing system in silex, it treats the url as a route (obviously) and throws a Page Not Found error.

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure your web server in a way that it does not forward existing files to the front controller. The [web servers](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html) section of the silex documentation has examples of such configurations for the most popular web servers.

As for the link itself, just link to the file directly, something along these lines:

```
<a href="/docs/{{ filename|url_encode }}">{{ filename }}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, all of the info you gave is great. As it turns out it wasn't working for me because I had a subtle url typo. I hate it when that happens! =/